# Why are my pushed values in the array undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am currently doing a personality quiz which pushes an answer value into an array in which later I would count the different answer values to determine what personality trait the user has the most/least.

However, when the answer value of an option gets pushed into the array it is *undefined*. What is the problem?

HTML:

```
<ul data-quiz-question="1">
    <li class="quiz-answer" data-quiz-answer="2">Blue is my favorite color.</li>
    <li class="quiz-answer" data-quiz-answer="3">Red is my favorite color.</li>
</ul>
<ul data-quiz-question="2">
    <li class="quiz-answer" data-quiz-answer="3">I like apples.</li>
    <li class="quiz-answer" data-quiz-answer="4">I like oranges.</li>
</ul>
```

js:

```
var ansBank = [];

$('ul[data-quiz-question]').each(function(i){
    var $this = $(this),
        chosenAnswer = $this.find('.quiz-answer.active').data('quiz-answer');

    $this.click(function(){
        console.log("Chosen option has been pushed.");
        ansBank.push(chosenAnswer);
    });
});
```

Comment: move `chosenAnswer = $this.find('.quiz-answer.active').data('quiz-answer');
` inside your click

Comment: Yup! Thank you that did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var ansBank = [];

$('ul[data-quiz-question]').each(function(i) {
  var $this = $(this);

  $this.click(function() {
    var chosenAnswer = $this.find('.quiz-answer').data('quiz-answer');
    console.log("Chosen option '" + chosenAnswer + "' has been pushed.");
    ansBank.push(chosenAnswer);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul data-quiz-question="1">
  <li class="quiz-answer" data-quiz-answer="2">Blue is my favorite color.</li>
  <li class="quiz-answer" data-quiz-answer="3">Red is my favorite color.</li>
</ul>
<ul data-quiz-question="2">
  <li class="quiz-answer" data-quiz-answer="3">I like apples.</li>
  <li class="quiz-answer" data-quiz-answer="4">I like oranges.</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Better 
Try with `e.target` .No need to use each function straightly apply the click event with `$('ul[data-quiz-question]').` and push the target element attr to the array

```js
var ansBank = [];

$('ul[data-quiz-question]').click(function(e) {
  var chosenAnswer = $(e.target).attr('data-quiz-answer');
  ansBank.push(chosenAnswer);
  console.log(ansBank)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul data-quiz-question="1">
  <li class="quiz-answer" data-quiz-answer="2">Blue is my favorite color.</li>
  <li class="quiz-answer" data-quiz-answer="3">Red is my favorite color.</li>
</ul>
<ul data-quiz-question="2">
  <li class="quiz-answer" data-quiz-answer="3">I like apples.</li>
  <li class="quiz-answer" data-quiz-answer="4">I like oranges.</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any `active` class on your `li` elements.

So I belive your code should look like this:

```
var ansBank = [];

$('ul[data-quiz-question]').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
    chosenAnswer = $this.find('.quiz-answer').data('quiz-answer');
    console.log("Chosen option has been pushed.");
    ansBank.push(chosenAnswer);
    //console.log(ansBank); //uncomment if you want to check
});
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Teo_van_kot/umvp1gjj/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var ansBank = [];

$('ul[data-quiz-question]').click(function(e){
  var target = $(e.target)
  if(target.hasClass('quiz-answer')){
      ansBank.push(target.data('quiz-answer'));
      console.log("Chosen option has been pushed.");
      console.log(ansBank)
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul data-quiz-question="1">
    <li class="quiz-answer" data-quiz-answer="2">Blue is my favorite color.</li>
    <li class="quiz-answer" data-quiz-answer="3">Red is my favorite color.</li>
</ul>
<ul data-quiz-question="2">
    <li class="quiz-answer" data-quiz-answer="3">I like apples.</li>
    <li class="quiz-answer" data-quiz-answer="4">I like oranges.</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

You must add class value in ul tag like this

```
<ul class="data-quiz-question" data-quiz-question="1">
```

Comment: OP is using the attribute selector, so a class isn't needed.